# Exporting an empty or node based blender model using Chilli Source model exporter

Tags: java, blender

Apologies for not using any tags related to the Chilli Source engine, but it's a new engine and doesn't appear to have any tags yet.

What I'm trying to achieve is a 2D looking object (made up of planes or sprite components) from a simple node based model. This is so I can swap the parts of the body around (head, body, etc) without having multiple materials for each character or moving UVs around the place.

I've tried exporting empties and armatures but neither produce anything when run though the exporter. I get a little lost in the tool within the CSModelConverter. It appears the nodes wont export because they're of type COLLADA_NODE_TYPE.BASE instead of either CONTROLLER or GEOMETRY.

Here is what is produced in the DAE with the empty nodes (Doesn't format well, blame blender).

```
<node id="LeftLegNode" name="LeftLegNode" type="NODE">
    <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.201311 0 7.54979e-8 -1 0.04089412 0 1 7.54979e-8 0.8485807 0 0 0 1</matrix>
  </node>
```

It's a simple transform that looks like it should be compatable but I think where it fails is the fact it has no material and geometry. It doesn't have UVs either, but I guess they might not be required.

I might be trying to do things the difficult way by changing the exporter to support empty blender objects. Is there any way to achieve this in the model exporter without either writing my own collada parser or heavily modifying the one with Chilli Source?

Here's the full dae file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <asset>
    <contributor>
      <author>Blender User</author>
      <authoring_tool>Blender 2.72.0 commit date:2014-10-21, commit time:11:38, hash:9e963ae</authoring_tool>
    </contributor>
    <created>2014-11-03T13:29:40</created>
    <modified>2014-11-03T13:29:40</modified>
    <unit name="meter" meter="1"/>
    <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
  </asset>
  <library_images/>
  <library_effects/>
  <library_controllers/>
  <library_visual_scenes>
    <visual_scene id="Scene" name="Scene">
      <node id="RightHandNode" name="RightHandNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0.01576674 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.3080968 0 1 7.54979e-8 1.016 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="LeftHandNode" name="LeftHandNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.781394 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.3080968 0 1 7.54979e-8 1.016 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="LeftLegNode" name="LeftLegNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.201311 0 7.54979e-8 -1 0.04089412 0 1 7.54979e-8 0.8485807 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="BodyNode" name="BodyNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0.9169789 0 7.54979e-8 -1 0 0 1 7.54979e-8 1.438218 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="EarNode" name="EarNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0.6259508 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.1329943 0 1 7.54979e-8 2.138675 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="HairNode" name="HairNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">0.7933933 0 0 1.228412 0 5.98995e-8 -0.7933933 -0.2107617 0 0.7933933 5.98995e-8 2.458043 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="LeftEyeNode" name="LeftEyeNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.714596 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.1349886 0 1 7.54979e-8 2.185041 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="RightLegNode" name="RightLegNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0.5970358 0 7.54979e-8 -1 0.04089412 0 1 7.54979e-8 0.8485807 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="MouthNode" name="MouthNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.45392 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.07053024 0 1 7.54979e-8 1.905577 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="RightEyeNode" name="RightEyeNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.194536 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.134 0 1 7.54979e-8 2.185 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
      <node id="HeadNode" name="HeadNode" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 1.226985 0 7.54979e-8 -1 -0.04570943 0 1 7.54979e-8 2.166729 0 0 0 1</matrix>
      </node>
    </visual_scene>
  </library_visual_scenes>
  <scene>
    <instance_visual_scene url="#Scene"/>
  </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ColladaToCSModel conversion tool doesn't support exporting models without model data and I'm afraid it doesn't look like adding support would be trivial. Even if the exporter could be changed to support it I doubt the engine would handle it.

I think your best bet would be to write your own system for handling this. It wouldn't be hard to write a Chilli Source Component for node animation, the only difficult part would be retrieving the data from blender. It's probably easiest to stick with Collada for this and write a Chilli Source Resource Provider that parses it directly. The Collada format can be quite daunting, there is a lot of information in it, but the scene node hierarchy and animation data are quite easy to retrieve without getting your hands too dirty.

If parsing collada is going to be too slow for your game, you could write a simple converter to your own format which contains only the information you need, then write a CS Resource Provider which parses this.